# Org-mode: Using sparse tree to search through timestamps (non-scheduled, non-deadlines)

Tags: org-mode, search

I am aware that I able to use sparse tree to search "[b]efore-date" with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> or search "[a]fter-date" with
<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

However, I recognise that seems to only be with dates that are **schedules** or **deadlines**.

Is it possible to use sparse tree or something similar to filter my org-mode bullets by time-stamps? Say in the context of using org-mode to do a logbook/diary of sorts.

Or is the best solution input the time-stamps as schedules?

Answer (score 2):

When you bring up `org-sparse-tree`, pressing <kbd>c</kbd> should cycle you through date types.

The first date type after the default of **scheduled/deadline** is **all timestamps**.  That includes normal timestamps.

So: <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> should do what you need.

Comment: Oh wow, yes that's what I wanted! I somehow missed that part out when I tried to search around. Thank you!